# "How does/can one ..." translation to Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, sentence-translation

How does one translate to Latin sentences like:

> 1. How does one do that?
> 2. One could try but he would fail.
> 3. Can one do this?

I.e. sentences using ***one*** as subject, where particular subject is not really important to meaning of the sentence.

Could ***se*** be used? If so, how?

Comment: Immediate thought: *(ali)quis*.

Comment: @Draconis Thank you, I will edit question using your comment.

Comment: No need to edit, just leaving this here as a note (for others answering or for me to do more research).

Comment: @Draconis the question answered, I will not make edit:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is the indefinite *aliquis*, often shortened to *quis* (and always shortened after *si*, *nisi*, *num*, and *ne*). This literally means "someone" or "anyone".

Another is the reduplicated version *quisquis*, "whoever".

> *Quomodo aliquis id agit?* How does anyone do it?
>   *Quisquis conatur, deerit.* Whoever tries, will fail.
>   *Aliquis id agere potest?* Can anyone do it?

Answer (score 7):

I know of two options:

1. The impersonal passive; e.g., *quomodo illud agitur?* 'how is that done?'; *potestne hoc agi?* 'can this be done?'
2. The generic second person, which always takes the subjunctive (and which most grammars try to sweep under the rug); e.g., *quomodo illud agas?* 'how do you do that?'; *possisne hoc agere?* 'can you do this?'

Answer (score 5):

You can use the indefinite pronoun: *quomodo aliquis hoc agere potest* / "How can anyone do this?"

See more on [indefinite pronouns](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/relative-interrogative-and-indefinite-pronouns).

Depending on what you're asking, generally a subject-less noun can be constructed with an impersonal: *licet alicui conari, sed non potest succedere* (It is permitted for anyone to try, but it is not possible to succeed.)